# Google Natural Language Sentiment Analysis incorrect result

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sentiment-analysis, google-ai-platform, google-natural-language

We have Google Natural AI integrated into our product for Sentiment Analysis (https://cloud.google.com/natural-language). One of the customers complained that when they write "BAD" then it shows a positive sentiment.

On further investigation, we found that when google Sentiment Analysis Natural Language API is called with input as BAD or Bad (pls see its in all caps or first letter caps ), it identifies text as an entity (a location or consumer good) & sends back the result as Positive while when we write "bad" in all small case, it sends negative.

Has anyone faced a similar problem? How did you solve it?
One obvious way looks like converting text into a small case but that may break some other use cases (maybe where entities do not get analyzed due to a small case text). Another way which we are building is to use our own dictionary of words with sentiments before calling google APIs but that doesn't answer the said problem, which may occur with any other text.

Inputs will help us. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The NLP API uses an underlying model that is neural in nature. The knowledge comes from training on real world text. It is normal to get different results for different capitalizations as they can relate to different uses of the same trigram, e.g. Mike (person), mike (microphone, slang), MIKE (military alphabet entry).

The second key aspect  is that the model is tuned and meant to be used on larger pieces of text and not on single words, hence good results can not be expected in this case.